# PHP validate URI

Tags: php

I want to validate a URI *(not URL only)* in PHP, though couldn't find any way to do this.

PHP does have [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) but it is [not for URIs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#refsect1-function.parse-url-notes), it would be helpful to find a proper way to validate URI structures such as the following:

```
content://com.example.provider/articles/?optional=queries
```

Comment: Oh well, it worked, Thanks @Skully

Comment: I don't see too much wrong with what parse_url does with such a value though, https://3v4l.org/rKN3J

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To validate URIs, you can use the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter with the [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function in PHP.

```php
$uri = "content://com.example.provider/articles/?optional=queries"

if (filter_var($uri, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    // Valid URI, do something here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Needs to filter as well to remove illegal characters.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com"; 
// Remove all illegal characters from a url
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

// Validate url
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
```

Here, the URL is required to have a query string to be valid:

$url = "https://www.w3schools.com";

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED)) {
    echo("$url is a valid URL");
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
```